# How to lag daily data by six months and populate a new variable with that lagged value?

Tags: sas

I would greatly appreciate any assistance on this matter. I've been scouring the internet for solutions but my issue has multiple steps and sas is rather new to me. I am using SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M7.

My issue is that I need to populate a new numeric variable named 'ME6' with the 'ME_October_t' from the end of the month, six months ago for each 'seccode' which is an ID (I have many different IDs). I used INTNX to calculate that lagged date respective for each 'seccode' and titled it in my dataset, 'date6'. After that, I can't seem to find a solution. I hope someone with far better coding skills can assist me! I'm at my wits end!

So from the last line of my sample dataset below which is for date 19770908, the 'ME6' would be 1425346000 which is the 'ME_October_t' value on 19770331.

```
data WORK.HELP_ANALYSIS;
infile datalines dsd truncover;
input data_date:YYMMDDN. seccode:6. ME_October_t:32. date6:YYMMDDN8.;
format data_date YYMMDDN. seccode 6. date6 YYMMDDN8.;
datalines;
19770104 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770105 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770106 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770107 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770108 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770110 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770111 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770112 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770113 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770114 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770117 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770118 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770119 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770120 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770121 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770122 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770124 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770125 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770126 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770127 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770128 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770129 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770131 1301 14253460000 19760731
19770201 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770202 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770203 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770204 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770205 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770207 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770208 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770209 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770210 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770212 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770214 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770215 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770216 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770217 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770218 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770221 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770222 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770223 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770224 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770225 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770226 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770228 1301 14253460000 19760831
19770301 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770302 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770303 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770304 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770305 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770307 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770308 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770309 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770310 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770311 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770312 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770314 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770315 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770316 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770317 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770318 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770322 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770323 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770324 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770325 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770326 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770328 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770329 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770330 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770331 1301 14253460000 19760930
19770401 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770402 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770404 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770405 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770406 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770407 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770408 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770409 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770411 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770412 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770413 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770414 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770415 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770418 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770419 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770420 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770421 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770422 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770423 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770425 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770426 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770427 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770428 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770430 1301 14253460000 19761031
19770502 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770504 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770506 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770507 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770509 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770510 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770511 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770512 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770513 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770514 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770516 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770517 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770518 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770519 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770520 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770523 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770524 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770525 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770526 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770527 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770528 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770530 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770531 1301 14253460000 19761130
19770601 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770602 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770603 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770604 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770606 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770607 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770608 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770609 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770610 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770611 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770613 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770614 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770615 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770616 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770617 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770620 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770621 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770622 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770623 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770624 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770625 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770627 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770628 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770629 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770630 1301 14253460000 19761231
19770701 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770702 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770704 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770705 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770706 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770707 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770708 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770709 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770711 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770712 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770713 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770714 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770715 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770718 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770719 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770720 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770721 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770722 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770723 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770725 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770726 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770727 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770728 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770729 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770730 1301 14253460000 19770131
19770801 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770802 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770803 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770804 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770805 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770806 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770808 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770809 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770810 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770811 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770812 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770813 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770815 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770816 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770817 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770818 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770819 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770822 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770823 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770824 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770825 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770826 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770827 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770829 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770830 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770831 1301 14253460000 19770228
19770901 1301 14253460000 19770331
19770902 1301 14253460000 19770331
19770903 1301 14253460000 19770331
19770905 1301 14253460000 19770331
19770906 1301 14253460000 19770331
19770907 1301 14253460000 19770331
19770908 1301 14253460000 19770331
;;;;
```

I did try the following code but it wasn't successful and resulted in 'ME6' being missing for all values.

```
/* Sort the input dataset by 'seccode' and 'data_date' */
proc sort data=have;
  by seccode data_date;
run;

/* Create a new dataset called 'want' */
data want;
  /* Set the input dataset to the sorted 'have' dataset */
  set have;

  /* Create a new variable called 'ME6' */
  ME6 = .;

  /* Use a BY-group processing statement to process each 'seccode' group separately */
  by seccode;

  /* Create a temporary variable to hold the 'date6' value for the current 'seccode' */
  retain date6_temp;

  /* If the 'date6' value for the current 'seccode' has changed */
  if first.seccode or date6 ne date6_temp then do;

    /* Set the value of 'date6_temp' to the current 'date6' value */
    date6_temp = date6;

    /* Find the 'data_date' value that matches the 'date6' value for the current 'seccode' */
    set have (where=(seccode=first.seccode and date6=data_date)) end=end_set;

    /* If a match is found, set the value of 'ME6' to the 'ME' value for the matched observation */
    if not end_set then ME6 = ME;

  /* End of the 'if' statement */
  end;

/* End of the data step */
run;
```

Comment: Since you already get `date6`, why not apply a self join by using `data_date` and `date6`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL and a correlated sub-query to obtain the ME_October_t from 6 months ago.  It's almost too hard to explain what's wrong with the code you wrote.  I guess you didn't see the `ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.`  Someone else will likely you show how to do the same with the `hash` object or a MERGE of the data with itself with a RENAME= option

Example:

```
Proc SQL;
  create table want as
  select
    have.*
  , ( select ME_October_t from have self 
      where self.seccode=each.seccode
        and self.data_date = each.date6
    ) as ME6
  from have each
  ;
```